# Not getting "Crashes & ANRs" in google play

Tags: android

I am getting feedback that the application is crashing sometimes but when i open "Crashes & ANRs" in google play it alway reports 0 new crashes. is there something i am missing ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you won't see any crash unless the users send them

Answer (score 0):

In order to get any information in crashes & anr's users have to click "report" when they got an information that it crashed. If they won't do it, you won't get any info.

Comment: after pressing report button i am not getting any error report